# Finding an interested value in a categorized variable

Tags: r, categorical-data

Could please someone answer me how to solve the following problem. 
A very small part of my dataset is:

```
X    Y
3000 4
2090 5
2090 7
3000 9
2080 28
2119 19
3120 10
3120 12
2119 12
3000 13
```

And I'd like to find out the summation(y) at each level of x. Also, please consider it is just part of my dataset and the categorical variable which is x contains 100 levels and the levels not have a pattern that I can simply address them like 1:100. 
Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use tapply or aggregate function to do this

Lets assume that 'data' is the dataframe that holds values X and Y

The commands are

`tapply(data$Y, data$X, sum)`

or 
`aggregate(Y ~ X, FUN = sum, data = data)`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with the "heavy machinery" (for efficiency, as `aggregate` is vert inefficient and `tapply` doesn't return a `data.frame`) such as `data.table` or `dplyr` packages, try (assuming your data set called `df`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(SumY = sum(Y)), by = X]
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  summarise(sum(Y))
```